# Openfire service automatically stopped in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, openfire

I installed openfire in my ubuntu system. Sometime it gets stopped automatically. After that openfire service stopped I manually restart openfire service. I checked openfire error log. I got following error.

```
org.jivesoftware.openfire.container.PluginManager - Error loading plugin: /usr/share/openfire/plugins/onlineusers
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amiadogroup.openfire.onlineUsers.OnlineUsersPlugin
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.container.PluginManager.loadPlugin(PluginManager.java:414)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.container.PluginManager.access$300(PluginManager.java:76)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.container.PluginManager$PluginMonitor.run(PluginManager.java:1068)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)

org.jivesoftware.openfire.container.PluginManager - Error loading plugin: /usr/share/openfire/plugins/clustering
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jivesoftware.openfire.ClusteringPlugin
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.container.PluginManager.loadPlugin(PluginManager.java:414)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.container.PluginManager.access$300(PluginManager.java:76)
    at org.jivesoftware.openfire.container.PluginManager$PluginMonitor.run(PluginManager.java:1068)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Can you confirm that it's not related to System Memory issue? As the logs which you have posted are not relevant. Instead of error.log, have you checked stderror log file? Is some error printed there too?

Comment: Oct 19 22:49:21 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx on eth0 to xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx port 67 (xid=0x4cd303a7)
Oct 19 22:49:21 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx dhclient: DHCPACK of xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx from xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx
Oct 19 22:49:21 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx dhclient: bound to xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx -- renewal in 1545 seconds.
Oct 19 23:09:01 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx CRON[21670]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean ] && /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean)

i got these error in syslog file

Comment: No man, i meant stderr file in openfire logs directory if it exists there. Runtime exceptions goes in that file. So i suggested this option.

Comment: I don't have syslog file in openfire log directory. I have only these files debug,error,warn and info log files.

Answer (score 0):

These log messages relate to problems with plugin loading. One plugin that's failing to load properly is the Openfire-provider 'clustering' plugin (which is deprecated, and replaced by the Hazelcast plugin). Another plugin that causes problems is a proprietary plugin called 'onlineuses'.

I advise you to shut down Openfire, delete the plugin jar file and folders related to these plugins from `/usr/share/openfire/plugins/`, and try again.